# Replace a part of the URL with dropdown value - onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a language selector dropdown in my site.

On change of the language the URL redirects to the respective site

My Current URL is 
https://www.example.com/mem/ca/**en**/pages/home.aspx

On change of the language, the URL should be like

https://www.example.com/mem/ca/**en**/pages/home.aspx - on selecting english
https://www.example.com/mem/ca/**el**/pages/home.aspx - on selecting Español
https://www.example.com/mem/ca/**py**/pages/home.aspx - on selecting Pусский and so on for all the languages

```
<pre>
$("#dd-language").on("change", function() { 
   var countryAppend = $(this).val();
   var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split('/')[4];
   var res = pathArray.replace(pathArray,countryAppend);
   var newURL = window.location.host + "/" + pathArray;
   window.location = newURL;
});
</pre>
```

This adds the value at the end of the URL but I need it to replace the language code in the URL

Comment: what values in your dropdown? please add your full code here to understand

Comment: on simply way using javascript --split and join with language value -
var t = "https://www.example.com/mem/ca/en/pages/home.aspx"
t = t.split("/")
t[5] = "pa" // language code
t.join('//')
resulte => "https:////www.example.com//mem//ca//pa//pages//home.aspx"

Comment: You need to redirect the page not just changing the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the array of the pathname split by `/`, overwrite the `[2]`nd item in the array with the new language, then join by `/`s again:

```
$("#dd-language").on("change", function() { 
   var countryAppend = $(this).val();
   var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split('/');
   pathArray[2] = countryAppend;
   var newURL = window.location.host + pathArray.join('/');
   window.location = newURL;
});
```

Eg, for

```
/mem/ca/en/pages/home.aspx
```

On splitting by `/`, the 2nd item in the array will be the `ca`:

```js
const pathArr = '/mem/ca/en/pages/home.aspx'.split('/');
pathArr[2] = 'el';
console.log(pathArr.join('/'));
```

so reassigning that array item and then joining results in the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector('#dd-language').addEventListener('change',function(){
    let url = window.location.href.split('/');
    url[5] = this.value;
    url = url.join('/');
    window.location = url;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression should be useful here

```
$("#dd-language").on("change", function() { 
   var countryAppend = $(this).val();
   var url = location.href;
   window.location = url.replace(/\/.{2}\/pages/,"/"+countryAppend+"/pages");
});
```

Example

```js
countryAppend ="xx"
console.log(
`https://www.example.com/mem/ca/en/pages/home.aspx`.replace(/\/.{2}\/pages/,"/"+countryAppend+"/pages"),
`https://www.example.com/mem/us/el/pages/home.aspx`.replace(/\/.{2}\/pages/,"/"+countryAppend+"/pages"),
`https://www.example.com/mem/mx/py/pages/home.aspx`.replace(/\/.{2}\/pages/,"/"+countryAppend+"/pages")
)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. But we are not sure the user will always land on  'ca' first

Comment: That is a lack of information on your part. Then we need to extend the regex